# Where do files have to be located to use algorithms on them (i.e. Binary Search)?

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search, piping

This has to be easy to solve, but I cannot seem to get it right.

My command: java BinarySearch tinyW.txt < tinyT.txt

throws: "The system cannot find the file specified"

My environmental variable classpath is pointing to the directory containing these files, so I assume that is not where the system is looking.

Where is the system looking for these files i.e. where should I put them?

Thanks for taking the time!!

Comment: What the answer said. Also make sure you use the piping correctly. Post your code if you still have problems.

Comment: I got it working, but thanks so much for your offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java programs read files like any other program: from the file system. If you execute a program from the directory `/foo/bar` and ask the program to read the file `bla.txt`, the program will read the file `/foo/bar/bla.txt`.

That has nothing to do with the classpath. The classpath tells the JVM where *classes* constituting the program to start are located. In this case, where the JVM can find the BinarySearch class and all the classes it uses, recursively.